# ずっと側にいてくれてありがとう, Why て Form?

Tags: grammar, て-form

For the above sentence pulled from Bunpro, the correct answer uses the て.

The translation is:

Thank you for always being next to me. [being there for me]

Why do we need to put くれる into the て?

Comment: By and large, the て is how you `-ing` your verbs. This isn't "thanks for be here" but "for beING here`. Just the same thing.

Comment: Counterpoint:  What did you think it should be, and why?  Maybe wanna edit that into the question.

Comment: I thought it would just be ru, since it seems like a general statement of fact.  But I guess that is better expressed with te form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ずっと側にい**てくれてありがとう**

The pattern is `て+くれて+ありがとう`. Formally, you can say `て+下さって+ありがとうございます`.

In this example, て simply joins the verbs いる and くれる to ありがとう, the order of which is fixed. To make sense of this order, think of the fixed expression `て+くれる`, "to do something as a favor."

> ずっと側にいてくれました。
>
> > You were always by my side (and I appreciate it).
>
> <sub>Note: the choice of subject in the translation is arbitrary as it's left out in the original.</sub>

Now, if we wish to be explicit, add ありがとう at the end.

> ずっと側にいてくれてありがとう
>
> > Thank you for always being by my side.
>
> <sub>Literally: thank you for granting me the favor of always being by my side.</sub>